# passing php to javascript onclick event using foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I am trying to submit a parameter using JavaScript on click event on a `li` item, inside a `foreach` loop, 
the answers are pulled out of the database and each answer have an id, I want to write the JavaScript code to redirect to another PHP page carrying the parameter, which I pull out with GET,

I pasted the code below for the `foreach` and the JavaScript function is called `clickFunc()`,

```
foreach ($questions_answers_list as $questionID ) {
    $questionID = $questions_answers_list[$answerCount]['questionID'];

    if ($questionID !== "$quesID") {
        $answerCount++;
        continue;
    } else {
        ?>

        <li class="answersList" onclick="clickFunc()">
        <?php echo $questions_answers_list[$answerCount]['answerArabic']; ?>
        </li>

        <?php
        $answerCount++;
    }
    break;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? Do you need help with javascript, php, or both?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: thank you i wanted to pass the id to javascript,then redirect to another page with the id in the url,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the PHP ID you want as a parameter to your JS function:

```
<li class="answersList" onclick="clickFunc('<?php $myId ?>')">
```

And then the `onclick`

```
function clickFunc(id) {
    console.log(id); //should see ID here
}
```